# Exception: You do not have permission to call hideColumns (line 25)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I try and run the following functions I receive the error: "Exception: You do not have permission to call showColumns or hideColumns dependnig on which function I run (line 25)." Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
function showVTTAColumns() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var VTTASheet = sheet.getSheetByName("LiveResults");
VTTASheet.showColumns(17);   // Column Q
}

function hideVTTAColumns() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var VTTASheet = sheet.getSheetByName("LiveResults")
VTTASheet.hideColumns(17);  // Column Q
}
```

Comment: If you run `sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);` do you get any protections?

Comment: I've copied the functions into a completely blank and new spreadsheet and I still get the same error.

Comment: If I call the function from a button it works fine.  Problem is I want a different action depending on the contents of a cell.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why or how but the following code seemed to do what I wanted and works:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var resultsSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("LiveResults");
resultsSheet.hideColumns(30);
```

It's no different to my original code so I'm very confused as to why it suddenly worked without any errors.

Comment: I ran into this too. If your original function was being called in the spreadsheet somewhere, it appears google sheets limits the scope of what your "custom function" is able to modify. This is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

getActiveSheet() doesn't take any arguments. It just returns the sheet that is currently active in the spreadsheet. Instead try

```
function showVTTAColumns() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var VTTASheet = sheet.getSheetByName("LiveResults");
VTTASheet.showColumns(17);   // Column Q
}
```

and see if that works?

Notes:

- I don't know if the exclamation mark is included in your sheet name (the name of the tab). If it is, please add it after the name.
- Also check if the column is protected. If it is, make sure you have permissions to edit.

---

### References

- [getActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSheet())
- [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

---

### UPDATE

It seems that you are trying to use the script as a custom function. Note that not every google script is a custom function. A custom function must have a return value and can not affect cells other than those it returns a value to. Hiding and showing columns with a custom function is simply not possible.

See this [link](http://affect%20cells%20other%20than%20those%20it%20returns%20a%20value%20to.) for more information on custom functions.

I'd suggest you create a function that can be started from a menu or from a button. This function can check the contents of C19 and then starts the appropriate function.

```
function showVTTAColumns() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var checkCell = sheet.getSheetByName('.....').getRange('C19').getValue();
checkCell === "VTTA" ? showVTTAColumns() : hideVTTAColumns();
}
```